# PHP 4 Compliance Checker

Tags: php, wordpress, php4

Is there a tool that checks your code and can feedback any PHP4 compliance issues? I've just developed a Widget for WordPress and haven't used any PHP5.3 features but have used PHP5 features.

I didn't realise the WordPress PHP version requirement was so low (PHP4.3) and am now contemplating the task of 'dumbing down' the code to make it universally compatible.

Comment: try using `var_dump(!function_exists("function name"))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine minimum required PHP version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924565/determine-minimum-required-php-version)

Answer (score 3):

You check your code with the PEAR Package [`PHP_CompatInfo`](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CompatInfo). Quoting:

> PHP_CompatInfo will parse a file/folder/script/array to find out the minimum
>   version and extensions required for it to run. Features advanced debug output
>   which shows which functions require which version and CLI output script

[Basic Example:](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-compatinfo.basic.php)

```
require_once 'PHP/CompatInfo.php';
$source = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'math.php';
$info = new PHP_CompatInfo();
$info->parseFile($source);
```

Also see the [User Guide for the `PHP_CompatInfo`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-compatinfo.php)

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem using php 4 function , first check the version of php of your server using phpinfo() and if it is PHP 5.x then check that whether u r using any of below functions

see the deprecated function given below

**Deprecated functions:**

```
- call_user_method() (use call_user_func() instead)
- call_user_method_array() (use call_user_func_array() instead)
- define_syslog_variables()
- dl()
- ereg() (use preg_match() instead)
- ereg_replace() (use preg_replace() instead)
- eregi() (use preg_match() with the 'i' modifier instead)
- eregi_replace() (use preg_replace() with the 'i' modifier instead)
- set_magic_quotes_runtime() and its alias, magic_quotes_runtime()
- session_register() (use the $_SESSION superglobal instead)
- session_unregister() (use the $_SESSION superglobal instead)
- session_is_registered() (use the $_SESSION superglobal instead)
- set_socket_blocking() (use stream_set_blocking() instead)
- split() (use preg_split() instead)
- spliti() (use preg_split() with the 'i' modifier instead)
- sql_regcase()
- mysql_db_query() (use mysql_select_db() and mysql_query() instead)
- mysql_escape_string() (use mysql_real_escape_string() instead)
- Passing locale category names as strings is now deprecated. Use the LC_* family of constants instead.
The is_dst parameter to mktime(). Use the new timezone handling functions instead.
```